# OneDrive and the Windows Dev Center seem to be out of sync aka Microsoft account Developer Center

Tags: azure-mobile-services, onedrive

Today I tried to update the settings for my Windows Store apps within the "Microsoft account Developer Center". I have two major issues:

1. Existing apps within the "Microsoft account Developer Center" cannot be deleted

When I tried to delete an app (that was not present anymore within the Windows Dev Center) I got the following error message:

[image: Unable to delete app from MADC]

2. When I tried to add a domain for a new managed Azure Mobile Service, I got the following error message

[image: Unable to register WAMS URL]

I am sure that it is not possible for two parties to create two WAMS services with the same name. I am looking for an explanation on how to fix this problems.

Comment: The only way to solve the issue (for me) was to delete the mobile-service and create another mobile service with a different name. I am not very happy about that.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in reverse order:

1. The error "The domain you specified..." indicates that another application has already used the domain you are trying to specify, or the domain is reserved.  To get an exception you need to follow the instructions in the link;
2. Re Deleting your application.  In order to delete an application that is also a Windows Store application you must delete it from the Windows Store portal. i.e. https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-US/Account/signup/start

Comment: (1) The first error should not occur at all. When you create a mobile-service within the Azure portal, that name is considered unique and is checked upon-creation. It is checked even for existing trade-marks, bad-words, etc. (2) As I mentioned before, the app was not existing anymore within the Store, that's exactly why I posted this issue. After a while I was able to delete that app. But I have no clue why this was not possible right-away.